# Closed subgroups of a topological group

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ is a topological group, and $A, B, C$ are subgroups where $B$ contains $C$, and $C$ is contained in the intersection of $A$ and $B$.

If $C$ is closed in $B$ then will it be closed in the intersection of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: I don't know much about topological groups, but for general topological spaces this holds by the definition of subspace topology.

Comment: The fact that these are subgroups of a group is completely irrelevant here.